# wordpress pass attributes from shortcode to java script

Tags: javascript, wordpress, plugins, shortcode

I created plugin which gets attributes from shortcode and passes them to java script and it works OK but I think it is wrongly written. Please tell me how to write my code correct way.

shortcode

> [yoolek-googlemap-v1 lat="51" lng="17" zoom="15"]

```
 public function __construct()
      {         
        add_shortcode( $this->tag, array($this, 'run_yoolek' ) );           
        add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'admin_menu' ) );   
    }           
    public function run_yoolek($atts)
    {
        wp_enqueue_style( $this->tag.'-css',plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ).'style.css');
        wp_enqueue_script($this->tag.'-google-maps', 'https://...');
        wp_enqueue_script($this->tag.'-js', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ).'script.js');

        $atts = shortcode_atts(array(
            'lat' => '51',
            'lng' => '0',
            'zoom' => '9',
        ), $atts, $this->tag );

        $this->admin_lat = $atts['lat'];
        $this->admin_lng = $atts['lng'];
        $this->admin_zoom = $atts['zoom'];

        $params = array(
            'lat' => $this->admin_lat,
            'lng' => $this->admin_lng,
            'zoom' => $this->admin_zoom,
        );          
        wp_localize_script($this->tag.'-js', 'MyScriptParams', $params );       

        ob_start();
        echo $this->admin_lat.",";
        echo $this->admin_lng.",";
        echo $this->admin_zoom;
        echo "<div id='".$this->tag."-map-canvas'></div>";
        return ob_get_clean();  
    }
```

In previous version i had all "enqueues" in

> add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'cssjs' ) );

in function __construct(), but i cant pass vars from run_yoolek to wp_localize_script.
this is my not working code:

```
public function __construct()
        {       

            add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'cssjs' ) );
            add_shortcode( $this->tag, array($this, 'run_yoolek' ) );           
            add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'admin_menu' ) );

        }           
        public function run_yoolek($atts)
        {
            $atts = shortcode_atts(
            array(
            'lat' => '51',
            'lng' => '0',
            'zoom' => '9',
            ), $atts, $this->tag );

            $this->admin_lat = $atts['lat'];
            $this->admin_lng = $atts['lng'];
            $this->admin_zoom = $atts['zoom'];


            ob_start();
            echo $this->admin_lat.",";
            echo $this->admin_lng.",";
            echo $this->admin_zoom;
            echo "<div id='".$this->tag."-map-canvas'></div>";
            return ob_get_clean();  
        } 
        /*ADMIN,PLUGIN HOOKS AND FUNCTIONS*/
        public function cssjs() {

            wp_enqueue_style( $this->tag.'-css',plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ).'style.css');
            wp_enqueue_script($this->tag.'-google-maps', 'https://...');
            wp_enqueue_script($this->tag.'-js', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ).'script.js');

            $params = array(
                'lat' => $this->admin_lat,
                'lng' => $this->admin_lng,
                'zoom' => $this->admin_zoom,
            );          
            wp_localize_script($this->tag.'-js', 'MyScriptParams', $params );           
        }
```